# Checkbox in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox, uicollectionview

Hello this question has been raised more than once here, but I can not find help
My problem is when adding Checkbox in UICollectionViewCell
Well, I've tried a lot of ways but to no avail
This image shows what is located in UICollectionViewCell

[image]

Well, when I click inside the Checkbox, it is his choice, but the rest of the foods are also selected, which I want to do, click inside the Checkbox when it selects box in cell and is updated the UICollectionView

**Custom Checkbox code**

```
var isCheckedGlobal = Bool() // !! Global Variable // You might need to change '= Bool()' to '= false' or '= true'

class CheckBox: UIButton {

    //images

    let checkedImage = UIImage(named: "checked") as UIImage?
    let unCheckedImage = UIImage(named: "unchecked")as UIImage?

    //bool propety
    var isChecked:Bool = false{
        didSet{
            if isChecked == true{
                self.setImage(checkedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }else{
                self.setImage(unCheckedImage, forState: .Normal)
            }
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        self.isChecked = false
    }

    func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton) {
        if(sender == self){
            if isChecked == true{
                isChecked = false
                isCheckedGlobal = false // !! Set variable's value
            }else{
                isChecked = true
                isCheckedGlobal = true // !! Set variable's value
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**cellForItemAtIndexPath code**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ordercell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SuperStarOrdersCollectionViewCell

        if isCheckedGlobal == true{
            println("Checked Cell \(indexPath.row)")
        }
        else{    
            println("unChecked Cell \(indexPath.row)")
        }
        return cell   
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your description of what you want to do is confusing.

I'm guessing that you only want the checkbox to change the current item. So if the user taps on the 2nd item in the list, that item gets checked but no others. Correct?

In that case don't use a global.

You need to maintain an array of information about each cell in your collection view. That can be an array of structs. Say it is an array of structs and one property of the struct is a boolean isChecked.

When the user taps a checkbox, use the indexPath of the current cell to index into your array of structs and toggle the isChecked boolean. Then in your cellForItemAtIndexPath  use the struct to configure your cell, including using the isChecked boolean to check/uncheck the check-mark.

Comment: Type the code for you? No. I'm not going to do your work for you unless you want to hire me to do so.  How about you try to implement what I described and report back if you get stuck?